# Is it possible to access state variable outside of react render function?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to access state variables outside of `render()`, but inside react custom component method?

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      "some url here"
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        const days = this.getRainyDays(json)

        this.setState({
          data: json,
          rainyDays: days
        });
      });
  }

 getRainyDays = (data) => {
    console.log('data inside getRainyDays', this.state.data) // this.state.data is undefined here
    console.log('data inside getRainyDays2', data) // data returns json fine
  }

  render() {
   console.log(this.state.data) // this.state.data is fine too.
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          Calendar showing {this.state.rainyDays} rainy days
        </header>
        <Year weatherData={this.state.data} />
        <Weather />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: please share the component declaration, and the state object definition.

Comment: Yes, you can. But it looks like you call getRainyDays before you setState. That’s why it’s undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to access state inside of a component outside of the `render` method.

According to the `React` documentation:

> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state` right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall.

Since your initial state most likely doesn't have the `data` property set to some value, it comes back as `undefined`.

You're trying to access `this.state.data` inside of `getRainyDays` before you even call `this.setState` inside of `componentDidMount`:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(...)
    .then(json => {
      const days = this.getRainyDays(json)
      this.setState(...)
    })
}

getRainyDays = (data) => {
  console.log('data inside getRainyDays', this.state.data)
}
```

But even if you called `this.getRainyDays` after `this.setState`, you cannot rely on `this.setState` updating your state immediately.

Again, from `React` documentation:

> Think of `setState()` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

If you would like to double check, however, that your state updates correctly, you can pass a callback to `setState` that will get called after `setState` updates component's state, like so:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(..)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      const days = this.getRainyDays(json)

      this.setState({
        data: json,
        rainyDays: days
      }, () => {
        console.log('data in state', this.state.data)
      });
    });
}
```

---

One thing that I'd recommend, is to check, inside your `render` function, whether state has the right data in it before you return some `JSX`. You might run into issues where some components expects an array of items and it renders it immediately, but you're passing `undefined` to it and it crashes...

```js
render() {
  // exit early and return `null` so that nothing gets rendered
  // if your API call hasn't finished
  if (!this.state.data || !this.state.rainyDays) {
    return null
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        Calendar showing {this.state.rainyDays} rainy days
      </header>
      <Year weatherData={this.state.data} />
      <Weather />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I see!! So the safest option would be calling `(getRainyDays = (data) => {
   // do something on data and call setState({rainyDays: ...})
  })` Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you need to access `this.state.data` inside of `getRainyDays` if `data` is what you're passing to it?

Comment: I was unclear on this concept and was thinking to use `getRainyDays = () => {// do something on this.state.data and setState on rainyDays}`

Comment: @jen007 Ok I think I see it now, you want to do something with `data` inside of `getRainyDays` then update the state with whatever the result will be... Am I getting it right?

Comment: Ok, got it! If you're all set now that's great, otherwise I can update my answer now that I know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh I'm good. Your answer is clear on how `setState` would affect `this.state.data` Thanks again!!